# Compress lowercase string into mixed case

Tags: javascript, url, compression, query-string

How can I compress a string such that:

- the compressed input is lowercase alphanumeric and the dot character (37 possible symbols)
- the compressed output output is alphanumeric mixed case only (62 possible symbols)

The input is short and has no significant repetition that can be taken advantage of by encoding repeated strings.

Comment: How short is short? We already know the input cannot be larger than 37, because of the non-repetition...

Comment: @Mark, why is it a problem that an input character cannot be the same in the output? The whole idea of compression implies that the input is *converted* to something else.

Comment: @trincot Ah. Misread it.

Comment: A remarkably efficient approach would be to encode eight input characters as seven output characters. This can be done easily with 64-bit arithmetic (only 42 bits are needed). 37^8 = 3,512,479,453,921, very slightly less than 62^7 = 3,521,614,606,208. The entropic efficiency is 0.99991.

Comment: Simply take eight input characters and encode them as a base-37 integer, where each character is a digit converted to the range 0..36. Then take that integer and write it as seven base-62 digits, where each digit in 0..61 is converted to the corresponding character.

Comment: I don't understand why the question was closed

Comment: It was closed for not being focused, e.g. there could be many answers to the question, and there is no evidence of any attempt on your part to solve the problem. What did you try? Do you have code that you tried that didn't do what you expected or hoped?

Comment: I'll repeat my question.How short is short?

Comment: There is no attempt to solve the problem because i have no knowledge of compression algorithms and didn't find anything online. Short is around 30 to 60 characters.

Comment: Sounds like you're not paying attention in your class that this was homework for.

Comment: You write 'compressed input'. What does that mean?

Comment: Meaning shorter

Comment: Shorter than what? It is input... "compressed input" is what you wrote. Compressed from what? Another input?

Answer (score 1):

You can encode *n* symbols from a set of 37 as an *n*-digit integer in base 37. You would map the symbols to the numbers 0..36 for each digit. You can then write that integer as *m* digits of a base 62 number, where each digit is in 0..61, and then map those digits to your 62 symbols. So long as 37<sup>*n*</sup> is less than or equal to 62<sup>*m*</sup>, then all possible sets of *n* input symbols can be mapped uniquely to *m* output symbols.

Here is where this problem seems a little contrived. It must be a homework question.

What you would like to find for an efficient coding are values of *n* and *m* such that 37<sup>*n*</sup> is only *slightly less* than 62<sup>*m*</sup>, so that the integer space of the output value is almost filled up. A quick search turned up that *n* = 8 and *m* = 7 gives a *remarkably* efficient coding, where 37<sup>8</sup> = 3,512,479,453,921, and 62<sup>7</sup> = 3,521,614,606,208. Those are really, really close. If I compute the entropy of those (log base 2) and look at the ratio, I get that this converts 0.99991 bits of input into one bit of output. An extremely small expansion in entropy. The compression is 8 symbols to 7, or 0.875.

This is straightforward to implement with just the integer arithmetic operations on 64-bit integers, since 62<sup>7</sup>-1 fits in 64 bits. In fact, it fits in 42 bits. This can work in Javascript as well, since it uses 64-bit floating point values, which have 52 bits of mantissa. Some care must be taken though in Javascript to avoid rounding errors. Or you can use BigInt's.

You use multiply and add on eight symbols to construct the base-37 integer, and then use modulo and divide to convert that integer into seven base-62 digits. E.g. to build the integer *k*:

```js
    let k = 0n;
    let b = 1n;
    // do this eight times
    {
        // for each digit d of input
        k += BigInt(d) * b;
        b *= 37n;
    }
```

and then to extract the base-62 digits from *k*:

```js
    // do this seven times
    {
        // get the next digit d from k
        let d = Number(k % 62n);
        k /= 62n;
    }
```

Repeat for each set of eight input symbols. Your input may not be a multiple of eight symbols, so you just encode as many symbols as you have left into the last integer, and then you also need to provide the size of the input, or at least the size of the input modulo 8, to the receiver, so that the proper number of original input symbols are extracted when this process is reversed.

Comment: Homework ? Take a look at my account history, I finished school years ago.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this could work if I understand it correctly:

```
const compressString = (input) => {
    if (!/^[a-z0-9.]+$/.test(input)) {
        throw new Error("Invalid input: must be lowercase alphanumeric and dots only");
    }

    const dotReplacement = 'Z';

    const result = input.replace(/\./g, dotReplacement).toUpperCase();

    return result;
}

const input = "example.string";
const compressed = compressString(input);
console.log(compressed);
```

To be honest this is probably very basic example but you can use it as start I guess.

Comment: The result is not shorter than the input.